# ddply() does not work with customized function when .parallel option is turned on

Tags: r, plyr

My custom function wouldn't be recognized in ddply() when I set .parallel=TRUE.

I'm trying to use ddply to do a parallel computation with a customized function. The actual code and data would be rather long and large. I found the following straightforward code is good enough to explain my problem:

```
df <- data.frame(val=1:10, ind=c(rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)))
library(doSNOW)
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK"))
my_square <-function(x){return(x^2)}
system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); sum(x)}, .parallel=FALSE)))
system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); sum(x)}, .parallel=TRUE)))
system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); my_square(sum(x))}, .parallel=FALSE)))
system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); my_square(sum(x))}, .parallel=TRUE)))
```

The first three ddply work well. Only the last line is not working and I have the following error message:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : 
task 1 failed - "could not find function "my_square""
In addition: Warning messages:
1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’

2: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’

Timing stopped at: 0.03 0 2.08
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, since the question was asked. But if others have the same problem:
I think you have to define the function you're using on the nodes to. Following works for me and it's the way I usually use it:

```
df <- data.frame(val=1:10, ind=c(rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)))
library(doSNOW)
library(plyr)
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl, my_square <-function(x){return(x^2)})
my_square <-function(x){return(x^2)}
system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); my_square(sum(x))}, .parallel=TRUE)))
stopCluster(cl)
```